# Time Complexity Hashing

Tags: hash, linked-list, big-o, complexity-theory, buckets

I'm working on an assignment for creating a hash table and one of the questions asks

> If we have M documents, and document D<sub>i</sub> consists of N<sub>i</sub> words, then how long does this simple solution take to search for a query consisting of K words. Give your answer in big O notation.

I assumed that the answer would be big `O(M⋅N)`.

Also, the second part asks if we use the hash function to be more efficient and all words map evenly across all buckets, what would the big O notation be?

I assumed this answer to be big `O(B/N)` where B is the number of buckets.

Are these correct?

Comment: It is not clear what "this simple solution" is. Could you provide an example and make your question more clear please?

Comment: By a simple solution, they are referring to using the easier way of iterating through every single document.